# Idiom meaning : Getting Hotter

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, exam-questions

In the context of below given sentence what is the meaning of this idiom / phrase ?

> The situation in Haiti was **getting hotter** by the minute.

This is a MCQ question with 4 options out of I managed to rule out two as they were completely irrelevant. I am confused between these two :

1. Growing in importance
2. Deteriorating rapidly

I tried to google for its meaning but couldn't find anywhere expect a mention in a book by *Sam Glucksberg* in this sentence : *She was getting hotter with every minute passing*. The meaning here implied is that she was getting *angry* with every minute passing which is close to my second option but since I couldn't confirm it from another source I am putting my query here. By the by if I put aside the reference which I gave and just look at the sentence, option one seems more appeasing, atleast to my ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operative meaning in that sentence relates to this:

> [**heat**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heat) *n*
>   7.a.  Intensity, as of passion, emotion, color, appearance, or effect.

This kind of intensity in a social or civil situation contributes to group or political instability (as in riots and other forms of civil unrest), so the answer would be (2) "deteriorating rapidly."

Comment: A related expression is to refer to the police as "the heat",  as in something you might hear a bad guy say in a movie "They're bringing in **the heat**, we have to go!" -- which is to say, the situation is "getting too **hot**" for the criminals.